# Numerical integration: The composite Newton-Cotes formulas, uniqueness and inductive definition for a given order of exactneness

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus, approximate-integration, simpsons-rule

I have a question on [Rabinowitz and Davis: Methods of numerical Integration](http://62.182.86.140/main/552000/305c1c878007a660426d9b1aa43efd1f/Philip%20J.%20Davis%2C%20Philip%20Rabinowitz%20-%20Methods%20of%20Numerical%20Integration%2C%20Second%20Edition%20%28Computer%20Science%20and%20Applied%20Mathematics%29%20%281984%29.djvu). They start to give a sequence for what they call The (composite) Integration Newton-Cotes formulas. This together with my problem is given in the 3 snippets below.
I would like to know if their procedure *and* this procedure in general is **unique**:
i.e. for a given $n$ equidistant points then $(2.5.11)$ with $(2.5.12)$ is the only way of choosing/defining the composite Newton-Cotes formulas: for $n=3$ we have Simpson's $\frac{3}
{8}$ rule and for $n=4$ we have Boole's $\frac{2}
{45}$ rule, etc. I would like to have that even the error will be unique in a sense, but can I expect that it will be literally unique that e.g. for the Simpson's rule it will necessarily be $-\frac{3}{80}h^5f^{(4)}\xi, a<\xi<b$, by the *sole requirement* that it has the order of exactness $3$: it integrates cubics exactly. **And not** $-\frac{3}{82}h^5f^{(4)}\xi, a<\xi<b$, say.

To reformulate this last goal of mine, can we really choose $c_k$'s and $d_k$'s in $(2.5.27)$ and $(2.5.28)$ resp.
**uniquely** as some definite/fixed rational number for each $k$ which is *best* in some sense ?
Could someone give a recursive/closed formulas for (the) $c_k$'s and $d_k$'s ?
I cannot find it in the book.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm a little confused by the question. To paraphrase a bit -- are you asking if, for numerical integration, like differential equation solving, there's actually a variety of higher order methods? And, much like you can choose from a variety of Runge-Kutta methods with different Butcher tableaus, you can do the same for numerical integration?

Comment: @AlexK OK. Please explain yet why "**And not** $-\frac{3}{82}h^5f^{(4)}\xi, a<\xi<b$, say." and I'll be happy to reward you the bounty.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't something I know a ton about -- but, perhaps a connection to explicit ODE solvers will help you make progress. With Runge-Kutta methods, given a desired order of accuracy $n$, you need $m\ge n$ evaluations -- $m>n$ for $n>4$ I think. But, then you have some degrees of freedom left over that are used to optimize things like stability. That suggests the same may be true of numerical integration. But, those degrees of freedom couple into the subdivision of the independent variable step. In this case, that is uniform. So there may be only one solution.

Comment: Ignoring boundary conditions, if you subdivide an interval into $n$ steps (giving $n+1$ function values) you can exactly fit a $n$'th order polynomial on that interval; then calculate the integral of that. Naively, that suggests uniqueness (exact polynomial fitting) -- but... If you consider $\int_0^1 a_0+a_1 x+a_2x^2+a_3 x^3 dx=a_0+\tfrac{a_1}2 +\tfrac{a_2}3+\tfrac{a_3}4$, that has a lot of null space over $a_{0\dots3}$. That might give you some freedom in how you fit the function.

Comment: @AlexK Have you written these 2 comments as a (partial) answer I'd awarded you the bounty, try it please !